# How to print more than one id values in Another grid?

Tags: asp.net

hai.In .net iam doing one application.In that one grid contain the id values.When we click on one values that id information is placed in another grid.And when we select another id then print the both id numbers information on second grid.Both grids are in same page side by side.Please give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first Gridview you can use `SelectedIndexChanged` event to read content of selected row and at the same time you can insert that row into second grid.

Comment: first grid contain only id values.When we select that one that id information coming from database.I already get the data individually means display only selected id information only,not dispaly previous id numbers information.